# Use privately hosted build agent to pull source code in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I want to be able to restrict access to our bitbucket repos, but without having to update the list every Wednesday (Microsoft [releases a list of IPs every week](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653) which you need to feed into your bitbucket settings in order to whitelist your builds).

I've spun up a privately hosted Azure VM and installed a number of build agents on the machine. I've whitelisted the VM's public IP in our bitbucket account... however the builds are still failing with the error below.

> The pipeline is not valid. Couldn't get latest source version for Bitbucket repo templumdigital/authservice, ref refs/heads/develop. Error: To access this repository, an admin must whitelist your IP.

I can, however, ssh into the VM and manually clone a repo so, it seems, despite privately hosting our builds the pipeline is still somehow using an MS IP address.

Does anyone know of a way to force an Azure DevOps pipeline to make a git call, in the "get sources" task, from a privately hosted VM?

Comment: Note: By default Azure VM's have a dynamic IP address. You need to configure static IP address manually.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal